# Ошибки в построении предложений

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть два предложения.Я их одредактировал.Но что-то не звучит. Может, кто-н. предложит лучшие варианты.

К примеру, Штольц воспринимал счастье жить здоровой, полноценной жизнью, а Обломов счастьем считал лежать целыми днями на диване и ничего не делать.

3. Я не могу не согласиться с В.Амлинским, так как в настоящее время тоже встречал человека, который помог мне в трудную минуту, которому я очень благодарен.

К примеру, счастье в понимании Штольца -  жить здоровой, полноценной жизнью, а для Обломова счастьем **было** лежать целыми днями на диване и ничего не делать.

3. Я не могу не согласиться с В.Амлинским, так как в настоящее время тоже встречал человека, который помог мне в трудную минуту, и я ему очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианты редактирования:

К примеру, если для Штольца счастье означало жить здоровой, полноценной жизнью, то для Обломова вершиной счастья было лежать целыми днями на  диване и ничего не делать.

Не могу не согласиться с В. Амлинским, ведь и в нынешние времена мне довелось встретить человека, который помог в трудную минуту и которому я очень благодарен.